# Express POST request body is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've been working on troubleshooting a very simple application and cannot assess why the request body of POST is undefined. I have used express.json() and body-parser and changed the Content-Type of the request to different formats and have gotten nothing back.

This is the backend code relevant to the issue

```
const morgan = require("morgan");
const { response } = require("express");
const { format } = require("morgan");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");

app.use(express.static("build"));
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(morgan("combined"));

app.post("/api/phonebook/", (req, res) => {
  const body = req.body;
  console.log(req.body);
  console.log(body.content);
  if (!body.name) {
    return res.status(404).json({
      error: "no name",
    });
  }

  const personObj = {
    name: body.name,
    phone: body.phone,
    id: generateId(),
  };

  phonebook = phonebook.concat(personObj);
  response.json(personObj);
});
```

And this is an example POST

```
POST http://localhost:3000/api/phonebook/
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "name": "Bob",
    "phone": 123-456
}
```

The server is up and running and doing GET and DELETE requests both work.

Comment: Try req.json() instead

Comment: Where is req.json() supposed to go? I don't understand your suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
POST http://localhost:3000/api/phonebook/
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "name": "Bob",
    "phone": 123-456
}
```

On request parameter body, `123-456` Isn't number so it should have " " to be "123-456". Because 123-456 type is null so the parameter is undefined. Parsing stiringified number into integer is needed on the server.

### Updated

Response parameters in callback func should be used properly. `response.json` on end of callback function should be edited to `res.json` as the callback function defined `(res, req)`.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I changed it to a string but the request body is still undefined.

Comment: @TaylorDean Seems `response.json(personObj);` should be `res.json(personObj);` as the callback function defined (res, req).

Comment: @TaylorDean Please to select my answer if it was helpful!